# What happened to OWASP ESAPI SafeHttpFilter?

Tags: owasp

I am trying to upgrade from 1.4 to 2.1, and notice that this filter is missing.
What has happended to it, whar is replacing it?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't around for when the version change moved from 1.4 to 2.x but have you looked into the [documentation](https://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/filters/SecurityWrapperRequest.html)?

It appears that they did away with the servletfilter approach for one that would allow you to override requests/responses from the one used in the reference implmenetation.